# what type of solder do I have in this picture?

Tags: soldering

I have some solder that might be 30 years old. it has little ridges in it like the edge of a dime. does this mean is it NOT for electronics but rather for other types of metal to metal joints?

[image]

Comment: It's probably just witness marks from an old extrusion process. It will be almost impossible to tell you what type, but if it's very old it probably has a good amount of lead in it, and usually isn't good indefinitely.

Comment: Solder is extremely inexpensive, so if you are not sure if it is suitable for electronics work, I would buy new solder.  Given the condition of your soldering iron, a new tip (also inexpensive) will probably save you a lot of frustration.

Comment: THat's rather interesting solder. It may be of interest to a "historic village" or similar. As noted by others 0 itr MAY be reasonable to use but odds are it's best to use more modern solder for anything that matters.

Answer (score 1):

You can get some idea of the composition by looking at the melting temperature if you have a digital iron and at whether it solidifies suddenly or has a "mushy" range that makes it easy to get "cold" solder joints if the melt is disturbed as it is solidifying.

Plumbing solder was usually 50:50 Sn-Pb so it has a high melting range (183–215°C) and the alloy is far from eutectic. 60:40 Sn-Pb was used for electronics (183–190°C)

Eutectic Sn63Pb37 solder has a sharp melting point at 183°C.

If there is an unknown flux core in that solder it could be acid core, and very destructive to electronics (and even more so when power is applied).

Comment: Dors that look like a digital iron or are you suggesting the OP buys one?

Comment: @SolarMike S/he may have access to one. That one looks like a vintage type to me. Given the apparent surprising awful inaccuracy of a lot of the cheap ones, the suggestion may only be useful if OP has an adjustable iron (could just be a variac) and a digital thermocouple temperature meter.

Comment: I think some of the cheap ones use a random number generator :)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany  the OP asked the question because I seem to recollect back in the 80s that the smooth walled solder was rosin and the ribbed wall indicated it was for non electronic metal connections (i guess acid core). that doesnt ring a bell with oneone? thx